# Django - Object not save date in the format i need

Tags: django, django-models, datepicker, django-forms

(Sorry for my bad English)

I'm having a problem when I try to save a date but only in one model all the other models saves the date perfect. But this specific model saves mm/dd/yyyy and I need dd/mm/yyyy

this is the model

```
class CashClosing(models.Model):
    # Relations
    # Attributes - Mandatory
    date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name=_('date'),
    )
    cash_incomes = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('cash incomes'),
    )
    cash_expenses = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('cash expenses'),
    )
    cash_diff = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0,
        verbose_name=_('cash difference'),
    )
    real_cash = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('real cash'),
    )
    next_initial_cash = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('next initial cash'),
        help_text='Ingrese aquí el monto con el que abrirá la próxima caja'
    )
    balance = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('balance'),
    )
    # Attributes - Optional
    # Object Manager
    objects = managers.CashClosingManager()
    # Custom Properties

    # Methods
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'cash_closings:detail',
            kwargs={'id': self.id}
        )

    # Meta and String
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Cash Closing")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Cash Closings")
        ordering = ('date',)
```

This is the form

```
class CashClosingForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = CashClosing
    fields = [
        'date',
        'cash_diff',
        'next_initial_cash',
    ]

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    date = kwargs.pop('date')
    super(CashClosingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.layout = Layout(Field('date', type='hidden', value=date))
    self.helper.add_input(Submit(
        'submit',
        'Cerrar Caja',
        css_class="btn btn-primary btn-block")
    )
```

And here the view

```
class CashClosingCreateView(CreateView):
model = CashClosing
form_class = CashClosingForm
template_name = "cash_closings/cashclose.html"

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    d = self.request.GET['date']
    # Tomamos los gastos e ingresos del día
    self.today_incomes = Income.objects.today_incomes(day=d).aggregate(
        sum=Sum('amount')
    )['sum']
    self.today_expenses = Expense.objects.today_expenses(day=d).aggregate(
        sum=Sum('amount')
    )['sum']
    # Si no hay ingresos en el día se asigna 0
    if self.today_incomes is None:
        self.today_incomes = 0
    if self.today_expenses is None:
        self.today_expenses = 0

    self.today_balance = self.today_incomes - self.today_expenses

    # Tomamos la caja inicial si existe y sino seteamos 0
    try:
        last_cash_close = CashClosing.objects.latest('id')
        self.initial_cash = last_cash_close.next_initial_cash
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        self.initial_cash = 0

    if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
        handler = getattr(
            self,
            request.method.lower(),
            self.http_method_not_allowed
        )
    else:
        handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_form_kwargs(self):

    kwargs = super(CashClosingCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'date': self.request.GET['date']})
    return kwargs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(CashClosingCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['today_incomes'] = self.today_incomes
    context['today_expenses'] = self.today_expenses
    context['today_balance'] = self.today_balance
    context['initial_cash'] = self.initial_cash
    context['cash'] = self.today_balance + self.initial_cash

    return context

def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    cc = form.instance
    # Asignamos los valores que no vienen con el formulario
    cc.cash_incomes = self.today_incomes
    cc.cash_expenses = self.today_expenses
    cc.real_cash = self.today_incomes - self.today_expenses + cc.cash_diff + self.initial_cash - cc.next_initial_cash
    cc.balance = self.today_incomes - self.today_expenses + cc.cash_diff

    return super(CashClosingCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Well the problem is this, for example I send using get the selected date like this

> cash-closings/create/?date=03%2F09%2F2017

I select the date using JQueryUI datepicker here is the script

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#id_date" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
  } );
</script>
```

and put this in the hidden input HTML use this value

```
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="03/09/2017" id="id_date">
```

But when I save this in the DB Django stores march 9 of 2017 (mm/dd/yyyy)

Ii don't understand why because all the other models that I have stores the date perfect!

**EDIT: (temporal fix)**

I fix it converting the string that i receive from GET with the Date dd/mm/yyy in a date object using this in the dispatch function

```
d_string = self.request.GET['date']
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d_string, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
self.d = d
```

That solves the problem from now, but I still trying to understand why this model saves bad the date since all the other forms and models works perfect. I receive ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You should override [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format) in your `settings.py`:

```
USE_L10N = False
DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'  # Your desired date format
```

As said in the docs:

> Note that if `USE_L10N` is set to `True`, then the locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied instead.

So this is why you should also set `USE_L10N = False`.

*Note*: This sets the date format **globally**.

Comment: Same result, i set L10N to False and use that date format d/m/Y and get the same result, the only difference is that now the Django Admin shows 09/02/2017 (i try to save 02/09/2017) and if i use L10N True the Admin show 9, Feb. 2017... But the data to store in the Db still bad

Comment: I add a print in the form and the date goes perfect i get this
02/09/2017
And add other print in the form_valid function and there is the problem the date is there:

2017-02-09